# Logout of application on clearing browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have an application, I want to logout of it if user manually clears browser history, as it happens in "facebook" or "gmail", is their any event which notifies my application about this.

Need help,as I am new to web application development.

Comment: It's not history but clearing cookies that cause it to log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually such applications store user information e.g. login details, session time etc on client side in cookies. Once you reset browser history, it deletes all cookies and temp files.

So, using client side Cookies can be solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can use `addcookie()` to set cookie values and expiration dates. If the expiration date is `false`, then the cookie is deleted on session close (when you close the browser). Otherwise, it's set to expire on a certain day. These cookies are stored on the user's computer and can be changed/viewed by the user.

You can also use JavaScript to manipulate cookies like `$.cookie()` or `document.cookie` if you don't have jQuery.

if that helps